# Questions Concerning the Chase Test

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory, dependencies, relational-calculus

> 2. [5 Marks] Let R(A,B,C,D,E) be decomposed into relations with the following three set of attributes {A,B,C}, {B,C,D}, and {A,C,E}. For each of the following sets of FD's, use the chase test to tell whether the decomposition of R is lossless. For those that are not lossless, give an example of an instance of R that returns more than R when projected onto the decomposed relation and rejoined.
>
> a. A→D, CD→E and E→D.
>
> b. A→D, D→E and C→D.

For the question above, my work for each of the questions is below the concerns. Here are my main concerns:

1. Does the order in which you use the relations matter?
2. Can you end up with less tuples with the chase test?
3. Is my approach correct?

-----------------------Part A below----------------------------------

InitialTableau = T₁ ⋈ T₂ ⋈ T₂

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D₁ | E₁ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D₂ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

-----------------------ANSWER TO QUESTIONS START NOW-----------------------

a) After changing the initial tableau in a way that ensures that the FD's given in the question are satisfied, we get the following tableau.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D₁ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D₁ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

- Since we do not have an unsubscribed row, this relation is lossy/not lossless.

Example of an instance R (Were going to use the final tableau):

R₁(A,B,C)

```
+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  |
+----+----+----+
```

R₂(B,C,D)

```
+----+----+----+
| B  | C  | D₁ |
+----+----+----+
| B  | C  | D  |
+----+----+----+
| B₂ | C  | D₁ |
+----+----+----+
```

R₃(A,C,E)

```
+----+----+----+
| A  | C  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+
| A₂ | C  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+
| A  | C  | E  |
+----+----+----+
```

After Joining the above relations, we get:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D₁ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D₁ | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

- **since we have 2 more rows than the original tableau, this decomposition is not lossless.**

b) After changing the initial tableau in a way that ensures that the FD's given in the question are satisfied, we get the following tableau.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

- Since we have an unsubscribed row, this decomposition is lossless.

Answer (score 1):

**CONFIRMED FROM MY PROF THAT THESE ANSWERS ARE RIGHT**

2. Let's start by creating a tableau for each relation, then joining them together, and running the chase test afterwards.

**T₁(R₁(A,B,C,......,)) = Tableau of relation R)**

T₁(R₁(A,B,C))

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D₁ | E₁ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

T₂(R₂(B,C,D))

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

T₂(R₂(A,C,E))

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D₂ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

InitialTableau = T₁ ⋈ T₂ ⋈ T₂

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D₁ | E₁ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D₂ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

-----------------------ANSWER TO QUESTIONS START NOW-----------------------

a) After changing the initial tableau in a way that ensures that the FD's given in the question are satisfied, we get the following tableau.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D₁ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D₁ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Since we do not have an unsubscribed row, this relation is lossy/not lossless.

Example of an instance R (We're going to use the final tableau)

R₁(A,B,C)

```
+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  |
+----+----+----+
```

R₂(B,C,D)

```
+----+----+----+
| B  | C  | D₁ |
+----+----+----+
| B  | C  | D  |
+----+----+----+
| B₂ | C  | D₁ |
+----+----+----+
```

R₃(A,C,E)

```
+----+----+----+
| A  | C  | E  |
+----+----+----+
| A₂ | C  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+
| A  | C  | E  |
+----+----+----+
```

After Joining the above 3 relations, we get:

R(A,B,C,D,E)

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D₁ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D₁ | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E₂ |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D₁ | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

- **since we have 2 more rows than the original tableau, this decomposition is not lossless.**

b) After changing the initial tableau in a way that ensures that the FD's given in the question are satisfied, we get the following tableau.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A₂ | B  | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B₂ | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

- Since we have an unsubscribed row, this decomposition is lossless.